# How can I add a random effect to this stan model?

Tags: r, model, bayesian, stan

I have a model for estimating the intraclass correlation (`rho` parameter below) from `N_items` of observations on `N_subjects`. There is a fixed effect for each item (mean vector `mu`), but I want to also add a random effect for each person. I'm not 100% sure how to do this, but I have a guess and I'd be grateful if someone could confirm or correct it. Would I just need to change the last line to the following:

```
y[i]' ~ multi_normal(mu + gamma[i],Sigma)
```

where `gamma[i]` would be the random effect for person `i`? (And in addition, declare a column vector of reals in the `parameters` block and then give it a prior in the `model block`.) Or am I going about this the wrong way?

By the by, if anyone has any suggestions for making this model more efficient, I would be forever grateful.

```
data {
  int N_subjects;
  int N_items;
  matrix[N_subjects,N_items] y;
}

parameters {
  vector[N_items] mu;
  real<lower=0> sigma;
  real<lower=0,upper=1> rho;
}

transformed parameters {
  cov_matrix[N_items] Sigma;
  for (j in 1:N_items)
    for (k in 1:N_items)
      Sigma[j,k] <- pow(sigma,2)*pow(rho,step(abs(j-k)-0.5));
}

model {
  sigma ~ uniform(0,100);
  rho ~ uniform(0,1);
  for (i in 1:N_items)
    mu[i] ~ normal(0,100);
  for (i in 1:N_subjects)
    y[i]' ~ multi_normal(mu,Sigma);
}
```

Comment: Jeez that was quick. Why the downvotes?

Comment: You might get a quicker response on the [Stan Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/stan-users). That's where the developers and user's tend to hangout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the model specification question, you can specify the expectation of the multivariate normal likelihood however you want. In your case, it is best to declare `y` as an array of `row_vector` like

`row_vector[N_items] y[N_subjects];`

and then in the `parameters` block

`vector[N_subjects] unit;
row_vector[N_items] item;`

and then in the `model` block, build up `mu` to use for the likelihood

`row_vector[N_items] mu[N_subjects];
for (i in 1:N_subjects) mu[i] <- unit[i] + item;
y ~ multi_normal(mu, Sigma);`

You will need proper priors on `unit` and `item`.

Answer (score 2):

On the question of computational efficiency, change

`for (i in 1:N_items)
    mu[i] ~ normal(0,100);`

to

`mu ~ normal(0,100);`

because that reduces the number of memory allocations for mu from N_items to 1. Similarly, you can replace

`for (i in 1:N_subjects)
  y[i]' ~ multi_normal(mu,Sigma);`

with

 `y ~ multi_normal(mu,Sigma); # or mu + gamma`

if you declare `y` as an array of `row_vector` in the `data` block like

`row_vector[N_items] y[N_subjects];`

Also, if your prior beliefs are that `sigma` is uniformally distributed between 0 and 100, then it is more computationally efficient to declare those bounds in the `parameters` block

`real<lower=0,upper=100> sigma;`

and comment out its prior in the `model` block

`// sigma ~ uniform(0,100);`

Doing so is more efficient because it avoids generating proposals for `sigma` that are greater than 100, which would be automatically rejected and do not have well-defined partial derivatives that are needed for Hamiltonian Monte Carlo.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! I am hoping to get a response to the random effect question since that was the main reason for posting, but if I don't get one I will mark this as an answer.